# Imputing missing values based on conditions from one df to another in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have a 2 dataframes, df1 and df2. I need to add values from df1 to df2. They both have different indexes- and df1 is calculated by groupby and average from some 3rd dataframe. I want to use apply function or anything that i can reuse as this scenario is present in multiple columns of my output dataframe.

Assuming df1 is my first df and df2 is my second df,

if df2.column.row_value is null/na : impute value from df1.avg2 where name of df1 = name of df2
else if df2.column.row_value is null in avg2 column, then impute values from df1.avg3 where set of df1 is same as set of df2
else impute 0.000

Input:

```
df1={'name_set' :['aa_001','bb_002','cc_003','aa_002','aa_001','cc_002'], 'name':['aa','bb','cc','aa','aa','cc'], 'set':['001','002','003','002','001','002'], 'avg1(groupby name_set)':[2,3,nan,1,2,nan], 'avg2(groupby name)':[3,2,nan,3,3,1], 'avg3(groupby set)':[2,3,1,3,2,3]}

df2 = {'name_set' :['aa_001','bb_002','cc_003','aa_002','aa_001','cc_002'], 'name':['aa','bb','cc','aa','aa','cc'], 'set':['001','002','003','002','001','002'], 'data1':[2,3,nan,1,2,nan]}
```

Intended output:

```
{'name_set' :['aa_001','bb_002','cc_003','aa_002','aa_001','cc_002'],
'name':['aa','bb','cc','aa','aa','cc'],
'set':['001','002','003','002','001','002'],
'data1':[2,3, 1,  # (should be imputed from df1.avg3 where df1.set=df2.set)
1,2, 1  # (should be imputed from df1.avg2 where df1.name=df2.name
]}
```

the indexes are different for both the dataframes.

Please help me with this as i'am a novice with pandas.

Comment: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) can you provide code or text of input?

Comment: df1={'name_set' :[aa_001,bb_002,cc_003,aa_002,aa_001,cc_002], 'name':[aa,bb,cc,aa,aa,cc], 'set':[001,002,003,002,001,002], 'avg1(groupby name_set)':[2,3,nan,1,2,nan], 'avg2(groupby name)':[3,2,nan,3,3,1], 'avg3(groupby set)':[2,3,1,3,2,3]}

Comment: df2 = {'name_set' :[aa_001,bb_002,cc_003,aa_002,aa_001,cc_002], 'name':[aa,bb,cc,aa,aa,cc], 'set':[001,002,003,002,001,002],  'data1':[2,3,nan,1,2,nan]}

Comment: output required: {'name_set' :[aa_001,bb_002,cc_003,aa_002,aa_001,cc_002], 'name':[aa,bb,cc,aa,aa,cc], 'set':[001,002,003,002,001,002], 'data1':[2,3, 1(should be imputed from df1.avg3 where df1.set=df2.set)  ,1,2,  1 (should be imputed from df1.avg2 where df1.name=df2.name]}

Comment: The string is missing quotation marks, so it cannot be reproduced. I tried to reproduce it by correcting it, but there are too many cases like that.

Comment: @PandaKim, i have edited with quotes for the strings

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
out = df2.merge(df1.drop_duplicates('name_set'), how='left')\
         .assign(data1=lambda x: x['data1'].fillna(x['avg2(groupby name)'])\
                                           .fillna(x['avg3(groupby set)']))\
         .iloc[:, :4]
```

out:

```
name_set    name    set data1
0   aa_001  aa      001 2.0
1   bb_002  bb      002 3.0
2   cc_003  cc      003 1.0
3   aa_002  aa      002 1.0
4   aa_001  aa      001 2.0
5   cc_002  cc      002 1.0
```

I wish that you did not make the column names unnecessarily long in the example.